# determine a type that represents the difference a tuple and a partial of that tuple

Tags: typescript

The core of the question would be given a tuple type `T1` and a second tuple type `T2` which extends `Partial<T1>`, how could I get a third type which represents the sequence of items that are in `T1` but not in `T2`.

**Assumption** I am currently making the assumption that given a tuple `T`, a tuple that may contain the first item in `T`, or the first and second items of `T`, or the first 3 items ... etc may be represented by `Partial<T>`. If this is not correct please explain how this could be represented.

**Context** I would like to create a function `f` that takes a generic tuple of type `T` and an argument `a` of type `T2` that extends `Partial<T>`, the function would then return another function with an argument of type `T3` that represents a tuple that should consist of the items that when added to the first tuple argument should recreate the initial tuple. Such that tuple types `T2` + `T3` should equal type `T`, where `+` represents concatenating the tuples.

This is what I have so far

```
type R<T extends any[], T2 extends Partial<T>> = never; // this would represent the type I'm looking for

const f =
  <T extends any[]>() =>
  <T2 extends Partial<T>>(t1: T2) =>
  (t2: R<T, T2>): T =>
    [...t1, ...t2];
```

Note here there are three functions as the first one is just to provide the generic type `T` for use in the following two functions. If I were to call `f` as follows

```
const f1 = f<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>()([1,2])
f1([3,4,5])
```

I would like for `[3,4,5]` to be the expected type if possible.

Thanks for any help, here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBOECGATA9gOwDYigG0BGAGigCZyBmcgFnIFYBdAbgCh2B6LmAWhgUA-O1CQoAJQA8cCAA9gEbOgDOUVNhCFm5QVHmLlagAqokwAJapcMgHy2EUbBABuEJKyg8nECOigAFhC4YIHuEJwAxjgqwFAAZgjsUFAy+gpKquqa2rYAFACUCLbJqXoGmSZmltZ2+cDEAFywFEXwJSl5wBTN0jC6FLYFzXDtpSmEAHTTDeTTk91snOzR2LEJxI7xUiTkVFC0UAxQLPkFebsUzAXs8cQXtAwsBUA) link with the above.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wO1Y6m) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes that's great thanks. I have no problem with the `any` in the return but if you can explain briefly what makes it so it is needed would be cool thanks.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to the implementation because I thought you were only asking about the types.  Do I have to fix your `[...t1, t2]` to `[...t1, ...t2]` also or do you want to edit that yourself?

Comment: I would like to know if given your implementation of type `R` , and given a tuple type `T` and a partial of it `T1`, it is possible for `[...T1, ...R<T1>]` to be resolved back to `T`. I don't  know if it is related to the specific implementation of `R`. If it isn't feel no need to add that part unless you want to.

Comment: TS can reason that with `t1` of type `T1` and `t2` of type `T2` that `[...t1, ...t2]` is of type `[...T1, ...T2]`, even for generic `T1` and `T2`, but it can't reason that `[...T1, ...R<T, T1>]` is equivalent to `T`.  I mentioned this in the answer.  I could imagine refactoring your code to do something else, but if you're specifying `T` manually to start with it's probably not worth it.   Since you haven't answered about the typo in your question I'm going to go ahead and fix it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) with [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to "subtract" tuples:

```
type R<T extends any[], T2 extends Partial<T>> =
  T extends [...T2, ...infer D] ? D : never
```

We can verify that this works as desired:

```
const f =
  <T extends any[]>() =>
    <T2 extends Partial<T>>(t1: T2) =>
      (t2: R<T, T2>): T =>
        [...t1, ...t2] as T;    

const f1 = f<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>()([1, 2])
// const f1: (t2: [3, 4, 5]) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f1([3, 4, 5]); // okay
```

Note that in the implementation I just [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the return type is correct to avoid dealing with compiler errors.  The reason the compiler issues an error there is primarily because it cannot reason about [generic conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like `[...T2, ...R<T, T2>]` for arbitrary `T` and `T2`.  All it sees is that `[...t1, ...t2]` is of type `(T2[number] | R<T, T2>[number])[]`, which is correct as far as it goes, but not specific enough to guarantee that it is compatible with `T`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBOECGATA9gOwDYigG0BGAGigCZyBmcgFnIFYBdAbgCh3RIoAlAHjgQAHsAjZ0AZyipsIQs3IwKUEWInSACqiTAAlqlyCAfMYTsosVaPFSiAOkfLyj+3uwAzCEigARZlAA-H5QAFxQ2BAAbt6cAMY4ksBQHuaWgtbqdrLyzMYAFACUCMYWllCCKmq2Wjr6hiYFwMThysXwpeXl+cAU4QIwShTGha0lZV2WhK7NLo69AajSMBwA9Kuw4NAA5PnKhNgArgC2AEbeAQA+fIJDxgcn50jMhQrbUHrS2JjJS5J6AHNsKhTrhoMBMFBuDsYNt7PFEskPMQECl+CRyFQoLQoAwoCwCoV8hjKC92OsoAlsEkUi0oD0+kQcXiWO0zCSscymMx2FTJJgwfZcJgAflkcSufiXsUKZgANaoECcIA)